# Database Queries: Fast alternatives to Django's order_by()

Tags: django

I've been teaching myself Django and SQL, and one thing I've noticed is that when working with large tables (> 1,000,000 records), specifying an ordering is painfully slow. For example:

`Model.objects()[offset:limit]`

might take a few milliseconds, assuming `offset` and `limit` are a small enough range. However:

`Model.objects()[offset:limit].order_by('name')`

Could take 10 or 20 seconds, depending on the number of rows in the table. I understand why this is happening; all rows must be checked to ensure that the correct results are returned. I also understand that this is more an SQL problem and not a Django problem, it's just easier for me to explain it with Django code.

So these are my questions:

1. Since I see Django production websites display ordered data from extremely large tables, how do they achieve this without each query taking >10 seconds?
2. After I solve the first question, how could I extend my Django application to allow ordering of multiple columns (name, date, value, etc)?

My intuition says that the answer to the first question is to insert each record in the order I want it displayed so that no ordering is necessary when performing queries, but that seems difficult to maintain.

Also, that means that the only answer I can think of to the second question involves creating multiple tables that are all ordered by different columns, and then accessing it like this:

```
if request.GET['order'] == name:
    result_set = NameOrderedModel.objects()[offset:limit]
elif request.GET['order'] == value:
    result_set = ValueOrderedModel.objects()[offset:limit]
```

The code for these queries is rather simple, but I shudder to think of how much work it would take to set up a database so that queries like this are possible. Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you try to write raw SQL queries in Django ORM? That can enhance your query performance by multifold. And offset, limit and order_by will definitely be much faster with that.

Comment: The issue is most likely the (lack of) an index. Just add `db_index=True` to your `name` field and `migrate` to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, shouldn't be that slow. Try adding an index to the 'name' column. That should definitely get it back into millisecond range. For that many rows, an index should be expected.

Few other recommendations:

1) For readability, I would do offset:limit after the order_by like so:

```
Model.objects.all().order_by('name')[offset:limit]
```

2) If you still having speed issues, print the executed sql:

```
data = Model.objects.all().order_by('name')[offset:limit]
print data.query
```

and do some troubleshooting in a query tool, or try pasting back here if you are still stuck.